# Passing variables to embedded directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive `mydiv` which embeds another directive `myspan` inside it. So my index.html looks like:

```
<mydiv></mydiv>
```

and the template for `mydiv` looks like:

```
<div>
    <myspan><myspan>
</div>
```

and `myspan` is simply:

```
<span>asdf</span>
```

Now I want to pass variables into the `myspan` directive dynamically so I do something like this in `mydiv`:

```
<div>
    <myspan data-text="hello"><myspan>
</div>
```

and add this to the `myspan` controller scope using the directive link function (which basically takes all "data-*" attributes and sets them on the scope):

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
    for(var attr in attrs) {
        scope[attr] = attrs[attr];
    }
}
```

Finally, the `myspan` template looks like:

```
<span>{{text}}</span>
```

and it works well.

**Problem**

I now want to add a scope variable from `mydiv` to `myspan` from the `mydiv` template, so I do the following:

```
<div>
    <myspan data-text="hello" data-scopevar="{{mydivText}}"><myspan>
</div>
```

However, this doesn't work and the "{{mydivText}}" is never compiled before being passed over. I think this is due to the `myspan` directive being initialized before `mydiv` so `mydivText` isn't ready yet.

**Questions**

1. First of all, is this the correct way to pass variables into an embedded directive?
2. Secondly, how can I pass a parent scoped variable through to its child? Note, I would prefer not having to read the $scope.$parent etc from the child and rather have it passed straight in declaratively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First of all, is this the correct way to pass variables into an embedded directive?

That all depends on what type of scopes your `mydiv` and `myspan` directives specify.  Do they use the parent scope, create a new child scope, or use isolate scopes?

If your directives are not creating new scopes, both directives will have access to all of the properties defined on the parent scope, so you don't need to pass anything.

With your current implementation, using `{{}}`s, you'll have to use `$observe` to get the interpolated value:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    for(var attr in attrs) {
        if(attrs !== 'scopevar') {
            scope[attr] = attrs[attr];
        }
    }
    attrs.$observe('scopevar', function(value) {
        scope['scopevar'] = value;
    })
}
```

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6PGrj/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mark! Although this solution would work, I went with a different one whereby I read the parent scope from the child (which is cleaner for my implementation). Your pointer re scope  helped a lot though as I was using {} isolate scopes.